# Lucene: Find closest number

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am using **Lucene.Net** ver **3.0.3.0** and trying to find a way to search for an number (integer) and, eventually, get back the result where the closest number scores higher in the list.

For sake of simplicity I've simplified the document:

```
private void WriteDocument(IndexWriter writer, string product, int weight)
{
    Document document = new Document();

    var fieldProduct = new Field("Product", product, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    document.Add(fieldProduct);

    var fieldWeight = new NumericField("Weight", Field.Store.YES, true);
    fieldWeight.SetIntValue(weight);
    document.Add(fieldWeight);

    writer.AddDocument(document);
}
```

It consist of 2 fields: **Product** and **Weight**. This last one is the numeric field.

For test purposes I've inserted a bunch of documents:

```
WriteDocument(writer, "ONORNN", 100);
WriteDocument(writer, "ONORNN", 200);
WriteDocument(writer, "ONORNN", 300);
WriteDocument(writer, "ONORAA", 400);
```

The first 3 have got the same product code. The Weight can be any value between 1 and 999.

I can see `Lucene.Net` offers a way to search for numbers in a range using `NumericRangeQuery` but that doesn't help me as it doesn't allow to input the proximity values, only `mix` and `max`:

```
var weightRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("Weight", 1, 999, true, true);
```

Is there any other type of query I can use to achieve what I am looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not C# expert, unfortunately, so I quickly looked through what is available in the Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and here is the proposed solution (I will mix in Java code, but hopefully, you could understand it)

So, you need to use [FunctionQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d3/d43/_function_query_8cs_source.html) which isn't actually a part of Lucene 3.0.3 but it was ported for Lucene.Net. This query will allow to provide custom scoring based on the value in the field of the document.

```
Query q = new FunctionQuery(new DistanceDualFloatFunction(new IntFieldSource("weight"), new ConstValueSource(245)));

static class DistanceDualFloatFunction extends DualFloatFunction {

    public DistanceDualFloatFunction(ValueSource a, ValueSource b) {
      super(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    protected String name() {
      return "distance function";
    }

    @Override
    protected float func(int doc, FunctionValues aVals, FunctionValues bVals) {
      return 1000 - Math.abs(aVals.intVal(doc) - bVals.intVal(doc));
    }
  }
```

So, basically I'm creating a function query, which uses two parameter function and exactly calculates the absolute difference between **245** (my value of choice) and actual values.

I have following documents:

```
addDocument(writer, "doc1", 100);
addDocument(writer, "doc2", 200);
addDocument(writer, "doc3", 300);
addDocument(writer, "doc4", 400);
addDocument(writer, "doc5", 500);
addDocument(writer, "doc6", 600);
```

and the results are following:

```
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc2> 955.0
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc3> 945.0
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc1> 855.0
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc4> 845.0
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc5> 745.0
stored,indexed,tokenized<title:doc6> 645.0
```

The problems that you gonna face:

- There is no `DualFloatFunction` is the Lucene.Net, so you will need to somehow use what you have [already](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d8/dac/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_function_1_1_value_source.html). The one that looks most promising to me is [ReciprocalFloatFunction](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/d49/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_spatial_1_1_util_1_1_reciprocal_float_function.html). Another way is to implement your own DualFloatFunction.

Overall conclusion - it's possible, but you will need to spend some time adopting it to C# and Lucene.Net.

Full source of the solution is located [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene4/src/main/java/org/mystic/ClosestNumberScore.java).

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Tomorrow I'll give it a go and come back with some feedback. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately for you, it's still some stuff to do

Comment: It seems feasible, though. Thank you very much.

Comment: It works. I borrowed some code from different sources and managed to make it work. Thank you very much. I'll upload a simple project to show the solution at some point. Cheers.

Comment: What's the performance implications of this solution? I'm researching whether this is ok in Lucene or it's forcing a full scan on the index.

Comment: @Damiox it should be a function for each of the matched document in topN that you're requesting

Comment: @Mysterion doesn't it need to calculate the function for all the hits in order to get the topN later?